# Como evitar que un usuario ingrese texto sin sentido en un input type text?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un formulario en el cual hay un input type text requerido la pregunta es si hay alguna forma de evitar que escriba un texto sin sentido como por ejemplo: fuihqwfiuqwefhqrufhqr solo para cummplir el requisito.

Comment: Que tipo de input es? Es un email o un nombre o que quieres guardar?

Comment: es type = "text"

Comment: Me refiero a que informacion se supone que el usuario ingrese.

Comment: Es bastante complicado lo que quieres hacer. ¿Cómo diferencias un texto que tenga sentido y uno que no? Análisis de palabras, gramática... Lo normal es validar que no se introduzcan caracteres no permitidos o que tengan una estructura concreta, como es el email, un teléfono...

Comment: Podrías establecer reglas de validación mediante expresiones regulares, pero en si no hay una solución especifica, porque tendrias que determinar si es una palabra valida, la unica forma es comparando con un diccionario.